# A public struct inside a class

Tags: c++, class, struct

I am new to C++, and let's say I have two classes: `Creature` and `Human`:

```
/* creature.h */
class Creature {
private:
public:
    struct emotion {
        /* All emotions are percentages */
        char joy;
        char trust;
        char fear;
        char surprise;
        char sadness;
        char disgust;
        char anger;
        char anticipation;
        char love;
    };
};

/* human.h */
class Human : Creature {

};
```

And I have this in my main function in `main.cpp`:

```
Human foo;
```

My question is: how can I set foo's emotions? I tried this:

```
foo->emotion.fear = 5;
```

But GCC gives me this compile error:

> error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'Human'

This:

```
foo.emotion.fear = 5;
```

Gives:

> error: 'struct Creature::emotion' is inaccessible
>   error: within this context
>   error: invalid use of 'struct Creature::emotion'

Can anyone help me? Thanks

---

P.S. No I did not forget the `#include`s

Comment: "Coilette. Your death fills me wih sorrow,                         (angry) anger, (fearful) fear, (normal)                          every emotion an actor can display." -- Calculon

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no variable of the type `emotion`. If you add a `emotion emo;` in your class definition you will be able to access `foo.emo.fear` as you want to.

Comment: This, in combination with Kenny's answer did the job (Y)

Comment: Interesting to see how some people spot the inheritance problem first while others are more sensible to lacking variables :).

Answer (score 7):

```
 class Human : public Creature {
```

C++ defaults to private inheritance for `class`es.

Answer (score 3):

Change inheritance to public and define a struct emotion member in Creature class (ex. emo).

So you can instantiate objects of Human class (ex. foo) and atrib values to its members like

```
foo.emo.fear = 5;
```

or

```
foo->emo.fear = 5;
```

Code changed:

```
/* creature.h */
class Creature {
private:
public:
    struct emotion {
        /* All emotions are percentages */
        char joy;
        char trust;
        char fear;
        char surprise;
        char sadness;
        char disgust;
        char anger;
        char anticipation;
        char love;
    } emo;
};

/* human.h */
class Human : public Creature {

};
```

Answer (score 1):

`Creature::emotion`is a type, not a variable.  You're doing the equivalent of `foo->int = 5;` but with your own type.  Change your struct definition to this and your code will work:

```
struct emotion_t {  // changed type to emotion_t
        // ...
    } emotion;      // declaring member called 'emotion'
```